# Why are my source files empty when running grunt? "Destination js/output.min.js not written because src files were empty"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {    
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-ee") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                src: 'js/app.js',
                dest: 'js/output.min.js'
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            src: 'js/app.js',
            dest: 'js/output.js'
        },
        cssmin: {
            minify: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'release/css/',
                src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: 'release/css/',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'jshint', 'cssmin']);

};
```

### Terminal

Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task

> > Destination js/output.min.js not written because src files were empty.
> >     No files created.

Running "jshint:src" (jshint) task

> > 0 files linted. Please check your ignored files.

Running "jshint:dest" (jshint) task

> > 0 files linted. Please check your ignored files.

Running "cssmin:minify" (cssmin) task

Done, without errors.

Comment: seems as though it's not finding your `app.js` in the `js/` folder relative to where the grunt script is located.

Comment: If app.js and Gruntfile.js are within the same folder why would it not be able to find app.js? My js folder includes app.js, Gruntfile.js, package.json and two folders called gitignore and node_modules. Do I need to arrange the location of any of my files?